# Validation form does not work and has a strange behavior

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm learning to use forms and I have a javascript code that when I click submit the page shows an error but it does it in a microsecond so I cannot read it and the page refresh it self, I have no idea about what is wrong here.
Here is my html

```
    <body>
    <h3>Formulario</h3>
    <form name="formName" action="#" onsubmit="return validaciones()">       
    <h4>Nombre:</h4>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="validateName(this)" name="campoNombre">
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="opciones" name="opciones">
    <br>
    <br>
      <option value="1">Primer valor</option>
      <option value="2">Segundo valor</option>
      <option value="3">Tercer valor</option> 
      <option value="4">Cuarto valor</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="si" name="pregunta" id="pregunta_si"/> SI 
    <input type="radio" value="no" name="pregunta" id="pregunta_no"/> NO
    <input type="radio" value="nsnc" name="pregunta" id="pregunta_nsnc"/> NS/NC
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="condiciones" name="condiciones" id="condiciones"/> He leído 
     y acepto las condiciones
    <input type="checkbox" value="privacidad" name="privacidad" id="privacidad"/> He leído la 
    política de privacidad
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="parrafo"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Javascript code

```
    function validaciones() {
      let valorNombre = document.forms["formName"]["campoNombre"].value;
      if (valorNombre == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      console.log('Ingresaste tu nombre: ' + valorNombre)
      }

      var elementos = document.getElementsByName("pregunta");
      for(var i=0; i<elementos.length; i++) {
      console.log(" Elemento: " + elementos[i].value + "\n Seleccionado: " + 
      elementos[i].checked)
      }
      return false
      };    

      function validateName(item){
      value = item.value;
      console.log(value)
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you submit a form, the page is reloaded by default. You will have to use something like the following:

```js
document.forms["formname"].addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  validaciones();
});
```

That prevents the browser from reloading the site, if the form is submitted.

Comment: Sorry about the stupid question but ¿enter is the same as submit?, because it also happens when I click enter

Comment: Yes, all browser that I know are submitting the form if you click enter on your keyboard.

Comment: Should I place that before the function?

Comment: It is not important wether you put it before or after your function declaration. JavaScript parses your document so that you can use functions before they are defined in your code.

Comment: It does not work. There must be some code mistake but I can't see it. Thans anyway

Comment: Yes, I see an error: I don't know, if this is the one that makes your code not work, but I have used `e` instead of `event` in my example code. I fixed it, maybe now it works.